# return the index of the last K non-zero element of each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is there a vectorization way of returning the index of the last K nonzero elements of each row of a matrix?

For example, my matrix only contains 0 and 1 and the last column of each row is always 1. Then I want to find the index of the last K, where K>1, nonzero elements of each row. If a row only has M (less than K) nonzero elements, then the index for that row is just the index of the last M nonzero element. e.g.

```
A = [0 1 0 1;
     1 1 0 1;
     1 1 1 1;
     0 0 0 1]
```

And my K = 2, then I expected to return a matrix such that

```
B = [0 1 0 1;
     0 1 0 1;
     0 0 1 1;
     0 0 0 1]
```

Namely `B` is originally a zero matrix with same shape as `A`, then it copies each row of `A` where the corresponding column starts from the index of the last K non-zero element of the row of `A` (and if in one row of `A` there is only M < K non-zero element, then it starts from the index of the last M non-zero element of that row of `A`)

Comment: Just to be sure, for any row `r` in `A` you want to get `find(A(r,1:end-1)>0,1,'last')`, but without looping on `r`?

Comment: almost correct, I want to find the last K non-zero element, where K is a given parameter

Comment: So you looking for `A(r,find(A(r,1:end-1)~=0,K,'last'))`, the whole part on the `B` matrix is really not clear...

Comment: I agree with you. But eventually, I want to produce a matrix B so that I could use each row of matrix B as some index set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that elements are only `0` or `1`, you can make a mask using `cumsum` on the flipped matrix `A` and throw away values with a cumulative sum greater than `k`:

```
A = [0 1 0 1;1 1 0 1;1 1 1 1;0 0 0 1]
k = 2;

C = fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(A), 2));   % take the cumulative sum backwards across rows
M = (C <= k);                       % cumsum <= k includes 0 elements too, so...
B = A .* M                          % multiply original matrix by mask
```

As mentioned in the comments (Thanks [@KQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378389/return-the-index-of-the-last-k-non-zero-element-of-each-row-of-a-matrix/39378818?noredirect=1#comment66087693_39378818)!), if you're using a recent version of MATLAB, there's a `direction` optional parameter to `cumsum`, so the line to generate `C` can be shortened to:

```
C = cumsum(A, 2, 'reverse');
```

Results:
    A =

```
   0   1   0   1
   1   1   0   1
   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   1

B =

   0   1   0   1
   0   1   0   1
   0   0   1   1
   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: In newer versions of MATLAB, `cumsum` takes an optional "direction" argument, so you can do: `C = cumsum(A,2,'reverse');`

Comment: @KQS Oh, that makes it much nicer. :D I'm doing this on Octave, which doesn't have that option, but I'll add it to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

knowing that `find` function can get indices of last k elements, we can use `bsxfun` to apply find to rows of a matrix to find which element in each row satisfy the condition. `find`  again used to extract rows and columns of nonzero elements of the resultant matrix, so reducing size of data and complexity of operations. then save the result to a sparse matrix then convert to full matrix:

```
A = [0 1 0 1;
     1 1 0 1;
     1 1 1 1;
     0 0 0 1]
k = 2;
[row , col]= size(A);
last_nz = bsxfun(@(a,b)find(a,b,'last'),A',(repmat(k, 1, row))); %get indices of last two nonzero elements for each row
[~,rr,cc]=find(last_nz); %get columns and rows of correspondong element for whole matrix
B = full(sparse(rr,cc,1));
```